# What do force extension graphs for springs show?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, spring

Say for example a 4N force is applied to a spring. The spring's restorative force will increase from 0N to 4N until the spring is in equilibrium. Throughout this time the resultant force acting on the spring *decreases* from 4N to 0N. Why do we draw force extension graphs as having 0 force acting on them when extension is 0 to having max force acting on them when x is greatest? (i.e. a straight line of the form F=kx)

Answer (score 1):

You have a point, but it comes from a misunderstanding. In $F = k x$, the $x$ stands for *deflection* and not *length*.

Typical spring performance graphs show force vs. length, where the free length is evident, as well as the intended working range.

[image: fig]

Answer (score 0):

The force vs extension graph which is drawn is not the net force on the spring rather it is either the external force acting on the spring (F = kx) or the force exerted by the spring (F = -kx) where x is the extension of the spring.

You could imagine a situation when the external force is increase from zero to 4 N in such a way that the resultant force on the spring is always very small and in the limit infinitesimally small.

Comment: You used external *or* spring force which means they are equal and opposite , so the net force on spring is always zero?

Comment: @dr.honey If the net force on a spring _weren't_ zero, then the whole spring would begin to accelerate in the direction of the force. Usually, in the situations in which such a graph is relevant, the spring is attached to an "immovable" object like a wall, so we know the spring doesn't accelerate as a whole.

Answer (score 0):

You may think of spring force to be a self adjusting force similar to static friction except that there is no upper bound. Since one end of the spring is attached to a rigid body, the net force will have to be zero as the spring cannot move as a whole. Hence the spring force is given as a function of extension as $F=-kx$